# Importing data from CSV to tensor flow, Invalid Argument Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use data i have in CSV files for training.
To use them I'm following these instructions: [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#*QueueRunner*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#_QueueRunner_)

since my data are no integers but decimals i have changed

```
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

to `record_defaults = [[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.]]`
so it accepts floats.

I still get following error though:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid float: 15.5
>
> [[Node: DecodeCSV = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_FLOAT, ... , DT_FLOAT], field_delim=";", na_value="", select_cols=[], use_quote_delim=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ReaderReadV2:1, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0, ... , DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0)]]

Which doesn't make sense to me, 15.5 is in fact the first cell from my CSV file and if it isn't a float, what else?

any help on how to eat with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show a longer stack trace? Also a sample of the offending line in the csv file?  Also, does the error still happen with the tf.data API?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known issue with Tensorflow when reading CSV using the `UTF-8 + BOM` encoding.  You should use your favorite (non notepad) text editor to convert the file to a normal `UTF-8` encoding then it should read the csv properly.

Issue for reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8415